# Saving success and failure results useing threadpool for concurrent requests

Tags: python-3.x

I currently have said function

```
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def get_url(url):
    return requests.get(url)
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as pool:
    print(pool.map(get_url,list_of_urls))
```

I'm confused as to how, I can append to a empty list say

```
success = []
failed = []
```

of the threadpool, when it's done I want to know what urls worked and what failed, and then print it, but I'm unsure if I would put this in the `get_url` function, or in the `with` statement.  And if it's in the with statement, where and how?

Answer (score 0):

Got it, I can iterate through the results by putting a return to the function,

```
def get_url(url):
    try:
        return requests.get(url), 'success'

    except:

        return url, 'failed'

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as pool:
    working = []
    failed = []
    print(pool.map(get_url,list_of_urls))
```